# Beginners php developer does using LiveDocx white Zend Framework is cpu resource eater?

Tags: php, zend-framework, livedocx

im beginner in the php world i need to build option in web application that can convert well defined structures 
into rtf/pdf from txt/html i found using this site search about LiveDocx php component that is dependent on Zend Framework 
now im not familiar white the php engine ( the parser ) 
so im asking you experts is it good solution to use this components ? or its just over head ?

Comment: hu no i see that this framework is just wrapper around some web service that doing the work of converting to document ..
not good at all ..

Comment: correct, LiveDocX is a web service, not a built in php module. You may not get too many answers here given your 1% answer acceptance rating

Comment: livedocx is a soap server, so you can use PHPSoap or nusoap to interact with the service.

Answer (score 0):

some simple to use tools:
if you want the easy approach try [dompdf - The PHP 5 HTML to PDF Converter](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/). It might work, depending on your html. you could also try ezPdf.

If you need to parse the html, try php's DOMDocument::loadHTML function. It will give you an object that accepts xpath queries for easy handling.

Comment: well its dosnt to be html at all , it will be object structure
that will contains the instruction on how to build the pdf/rtf .
so i need some kind of php tool that convert to pdf and rtf

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share my little experience after looking on the net a lot I found http://mpdf.bpm1.com/ this utility is a mix of libraries I´m  using it to generate invoices on demand.
I expect this can be useful to you.